# Windows 8 frees memory of inactive windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory

It seems like Windows automatically takes any window, that wasnt active for some 30-40 min, memory out of RAM (perhaps storing it on hard drive). Absolutely no matter how much free RAM there is, it would.

For me, the outcome is, that after this set period, the inactive window takes alot of time to switch to, and after it does loads from background, its still laggy for long after. Absolutely all programs affected, including extremely light ones as notepad.

Is there any setting that I should look at, to switch this feature (or whatever this is) off entirely?

P.S.
I'm running on 8GB RAM, which is rarely used by more than half. Windows 8.1

Comment: No; This behavior cannot be turned off.  But its also not the reason "switch to" is slow.  You have not diagnosed the correct reason for your issues.

Comment: What could be the correct reason? Anything I should read about? This behaviour is not something new, its been since the first launch of my laptop.

Comment: You're almost certainly wrong that you're rarely using more than half your RAM. Any OS that did that would be considered hideously inefficient. (It's not like you can use 4GB today so you can use 12GB tomorrow.)

Comment: have you disabled supefetch? this may cause your issue

Comment: A page file that was to small might explain it.  You have to determine if you are running out of physical or virtual memory.  The slowness would be explained the solution determines what is actually happening.

Comment: @Ramhound Exactly. With no page file or too small a page file, the OS may have no choice but to discard lots of clean pages, causing delays when programs that haven't run in a long time need to run again. (It's because their *code* isn't in RAM because it had to be evicted to make room for junk that couldn't be ejected to the page file.)

Comment: magicandre1981 it is enabled.
@Ramhound you might be totally right, my pad file was tuned inproperly, way below recommended settings. Just made changes and reboot, will inform as it develops.

Comment: As for now, looks like changing page file settings made the trick, and everything runs smoothly, just as I want it to. Thanks alot!

Comment: As for now, looks like changing page file settings made the trick, and everything runs smoothly, just as I want it to. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no page file or too small a page file, the operating system has no choice but to keep all dirty pages (that don't reflect permanent file modifications) in RAM. This means that clean pages get brutally evicted from RAM to make room for all these dirty pages. As a result, when you return to a program that hasn't been executed in a long time, the *code* for that program won't be in memory, forcing the OS to load it. This causes a delay and also forces other program's clean pages to be evicted, starting the process over again.

This isn't the only negative consequence of having no page file or too small a page file. But it's the one that's probably causing the behavior you are experiencing.

Also, you're incorrect that your OS is rarely using more than half your memory. It's almost always using almost all of it. Not using memory is a pure waste. It's not like you can use 6GB now so that you can use 10GB later. Any memory not used at any particular time is opportunity forever lost. No decent OS would waste so much memory unless it had absolutely no choice -- and Windows has choices.

Comment: How OS is supposed to evict clean pages from RAM to disk if there is no pagefile? Moreover, until the memory limit is met, the OS with pagefile disabled is actually more responsive, because it doesn't do swapping.

Comment: @beatcracker It just evicts them. It can read them from the file system if it needs them later. That's the delay he's seeing. I agree that the OS with pagefile disabled can be a bit more responsive at first because it is evicting only clean pages, which is cheaper that evicting dirty pages (since you don't have to write them out first). But eventually, being forced into that strategy becomes disastrous. If you think giving an OS more choices makes it worse, you think the OS was designed by fools.

Comment: Yes, I know how swapping and memory management works and I agree with you about small pagefile consequences. I'm just pointing that the part of the sentence `With no page file` makes no sense, because no pagefile = no swapping.

Comment: @beatcracker I don't follow. What makes no sense? Can you be very precise about which sentence you disagree with and why? With no page file, dirty pages that are owned by a process but don't reflect permanent file modifications can *never* be evicted from memory. That means clean pages get brutally evicted. So when you go to a program you haven't used recently, many of its clean pages will not be in memory (for example, its executable and libraries), forcing the OS to load them into memory. Right? And this will force it to evict other program's clean pages.

Comment: Ok, just to be very precise: `That means clean pages get brutally evicted.` By evicting you mean written to disk? Could you please clarify *where* clean pages are evicted if there is no page file? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @beatcracker When you run a program, pages from the executables for that program fault into memory. Assuming the program doesn't modify its own code, the pages stay clean (unmodified) and can be evicted (removed) from memory whenever the OS needs memory for something else. Since the pages were clean, they don't need to be written anywhere to be evicted -- the data can always be read from the filesystem. (This is why you can't remove an executable file while it's running!) If you switch back to a program and the code that needs to run has been evicted, it faults back in from the file system.

Comment: Damn, I knew I was missing something! Never heard term "eviction" before applied to the process you described, but that's just an artifact of reading about this in two languages. So I stand corrected, thanks!